# Azure VM gets Provisioning failed issue

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

when i try to create Vm from Image in Azure i got Provisioning failed issue

[image: here is the error image]

After that i can not connect to VM through RDP

Comment: Which image exactly did you use?

Comment: It seems you use the image which you created yourself, and you do not generalize the VM when you create the image.

Comment: Its custom image for LS Retail

Comment: @CharlesXu how to generalize that

Comment: Which OS do you use? Linux or Windows?

Comment: windows os i am using

Comment: You can follow the steps in [Generalize the Windows VM using Sysprep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource#generalize-the-windows-vm-using-sysprep).

Comment: Do you solve the problem with my comment? Please let me know if it works for you. Then I will add an answer to help other communities, and you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows that you do not generalize the VM before you capture the VM as an image. And you use the Windows OS, so you need to follow the steps in [Generalize the Windows VM using Sysprep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource#generalize-the-windows-vm-using-sysprep) to generalize the VM and then capture the image.